# Bug writing parquet files with structs using pyarrow

Tags: python, hive, parquet, pyarrow, apache-arrow

#### The Problem

I am having an issue writing a struct to parquet using pyarrow.  There appear to be intermittent failures based on the *size* of the dataset.  If I sub- or super-sample the dataset, it will sometimes write a valid dataset, sometimes not.  I cannot discern any pattern to it.

I am writing a single column, with the schema

```
struct<creation_date: string, 
     expiration_date: string, 
     last_updated: string, 
     name_server: string, 
     registrar: string, 
     status: string>
```

This doesn't appear to be a versioning issue - the write succeeds sometimes, and I've been able to successfully write even more complex data types like lists of structs.

If I unnest the struct so each property gets its own column, things work fine - it's something with how structs are written.

After writing to disk, when I inspect with `parquet-tools`, I get the error `org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at {n} in block 0 in file` where n is whatever row is throwing the issue.  There is nothing special about that particular row.

When I load the table into hive and try to explore it there, I get something slightly more illuminating:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Reading past RLE/BitPacking stream.
    at parquet.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:55)
    at parquet.column.values.rle.RunLengthBitPackingHybridDecoder.readNext(RunLengthBitPackingHybridDecoder.java:82)
    at parquet.column.values.rle.RunLengthBitPackingHybridDecoder.readInt(RunLengthBitPackingHybridDecoder.java:64)
    at parquet.column.values.dictionary.DictionaryValuesReader.readValueDictionaryId(DictionaryValuesReader.java:76)
    at parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl$1.read(ColumnReaderImpl.java:166)
    at parquet.column.impl.ColumnReaderImpl.readValue(ColumnReaderImpl.java:464)
    ... 35 more
```

Oddly, other data types look fine - there's something about this specific struct that is throwing errors.  Here is the code needed to reproduce the issue:

```py
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import sys
# Command line argument to set how many rows in the dataset
_, n = sys.argv
n = int(n)

# Random whois data - should be a struct with the schema
# struct<creation_date: string, 
#     expiration_date: string, 
#     last_updated: string, 
#     name_server: string, 
#     registrar: string, 
#     status: string>
# nothing terribly interesting

df = pd.DataFrame({'whois':[
{'registrar': 'GoDaddy.com, LLC', 'creation_date': '2020-07-17T16:10:35', 'expiration_date': '2022-07-17T16:10:35', 'last_updated': None, 'name_server': 'ns59.domaincontrol.com\r', 'status': 'clientDeleteProhibited'},
{'registrar': 'Hongkong Domain Name Information Management Co., Limited', 'creation_date': '2020-07-17T10:28:36', 'expiration_date': '2021-07-17T10:28:36', 'last_updated': None, 'name_server': 'ns2.alidns.com\r', 'status': 'ok'},
{'registrar': 'GoDaddy.com, LLC', 'creation_date': '2020-07-17T04:04:06', 'expiration_date': '2021-07-17T04:04:06', 'last_updated': None, 'name_server': 'ns76.domaincontrol.com\r', 'status': 'clientDeleteProhibited'},
None
]})

# strangely, the bug only pops up for datasets of certain length
# When n is 2 or 5 it works fine, but 3 is busted.  
df = pd.concat([df for _ in range(n)]).sample(frac=1)
print(df.tail())
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, preserve_index=False)
print(table)
# The write doesn't throw any errors
pq.write_table(table, '/tmp/tst2.pa')
# This read is the bit that throws the error - it's some random OSError
df = pd.read_parquet('/tmp/tst2.pa')
print(df)
```

Updates

- I've tried altering the *number* of items in the struct (e.g. only having the first 2 children) and that changes *when* the write fails, but still fails intermittently for some sizes of data.

#### Things I've tried

- Upgrading the parquet version to 2.0
- Disabling dictionary writes
- Changing the compression settings
- Changing some page file settings
- Using a defined instead of imputed schema
- Unnesting the struct (it works in this example, but not in my use case)

#### Environment

- `pyarrow==0.17.1`
- `python==3.6.10`
- `pandas=1.0.5`

#### Questions

- Is this a bug, a version mismatch, or something else?
- If the issue is on my end, how should I fix it?
- If this is a bug, who should should I report it to?  The arrow devs? The parquet devs? Someone else?

Answer (score 1):

Your Table schema has got nested struct. It's basically one column called whois containing  user defined types with  fields creation_date, expiration_date etc.

```
> table.schema
whois: struct<creation_date: string, expiration_date: string, last_updated: null, name_server: string, registrar: string, status: string>
  child 0, creation_date: string
  child 1, expiration_date: string
  child 2, last_updated: null
  child 3, name_server: string
  child 4, registrar: string
  child 5, status: string
```

Prior to `0.17.0`, nested UDT (user defined types) were not supported when it comes to reading and writing to parquet. But this has being addressed here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1644

If you're using an old version of arrow, considering you only have one column in your data frame, I'd recommend not using UDT:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'registrar': 'GoDaddy.com, LLC', 'creation_date': '2020-07-17T16:10:35', 'expiration_date': '2022-07-17T16:10:35', 'last_updated': None, 'name_server': 'ns59.domaincontrol.com\r', 'status': 'clientDeleteProhibited'},
    {'registrar': 'Hongkong Domain Name Information Management Co., Limited', 'creation_date': '2020-07-17T10:28:36', 'expiration_date': '2021-07-17T10:28:36', 'last_updated': None, 'name_server': 'ns2.alidns.com\r', 'status': 'ok'},
    {'registrar': 'GoDaddy.com, LLC', 'creation_date': '2020-07-17T04:04:06', 'expiration_date': '2021-07-17T04:04:06', 'last_updated': None, 'name_server': 'ns76.domaincontrol.com\r', 'status': 'clientDeleteProhibited'},
    {}
])

table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, preserve_index=False)
pq.write_table(table, '/tmp/tst2.pa')
df = pd.read_parquet('/tmp/tst2.pa')
```

Another option is to flatten your table directly in pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'whois':[
{'registrar': 'GoDaddy.com, LLC', 'creation_date': '2020-07-17T16:10:35', 'expiration_date': '2022-07-17T16:10:35', 'last_updated': None, 'name_server': 'ns59.domaincontrol.com\r', 'status': 'clientDeleteProhibited'},
{'registrar': 'Hongkong Domain Name Information Management Co., Limited', 'creation_date': '2020-07-17T10:28:36', 'expiration_date': '2021-07-17T10:28:36', 'last_updated': None, 'name_server': 'ns2.alidns.com\r', 'status': 'ok'},
{'registrar': 'GoDaddy.com, LLC', 'creation_date': '2020-07-17T04:04:06', 'expiration_date': '2021-07-17T04:04:06', 'last_updated': None, 'name_server': 'ns76.domaincontrol.com\r', 'status': 'clientDeleteProhibited'},
None
]})
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, preserve_index=False).flatten()
df = pd.read_parquet('/tmp/tst2.pa')
df = pd.read_parquet('/tmp/tst2.pa')
```

As a side note you may want to provide your own schema as pandas and arrow are trying to guess the type of the columns but they are not doing a good job for null columns (last_updated is defaulting to float or null)

```
> table.schema
creation_date: string
expiration_date: string
last_updated: double
name_server: string
registrar: string
status: string
```

So instead you could do something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'registrar': 'GoDaddy.com, LLC', 'creation_date': '2020-07-17T16:10:35', 'expiration_date': '2022-07-17T16:10:35', 'last_updated': None, 'name_server': 'ns59.domaincontrol.com\r', 'status': 'clientDeleteProhibited'},
    {'registrar': 'Hongkong Domain Name Information Management Co., Limited', 'creation_date': '2020-07-17T10:28:36', 'expiration_date': '2021-07-17T10:28:36', 'last_updated': None, 'name_server': 'ns2.alidns.com\r', 'status': 'ok'},
    {'registrar': 'GoDaddy.com, LLC', 'creation_date': '2020-07-17T04:04:06', 'expiration_date': '2021-07-17T04:04:06', 'last_updated': None, 'name_server': 'ns76.domaincontrol.com\r', 'status': 'clientDeleteProhibited'},
    {}
])

table_schema = pa.schema([
    pa.field('creation_date', pa.string()),
    pa.field('expiration_date', pa.string()),
    pa.field('last_updated', pa.string()),
    pa.field('name_server', pa.string()),
    pa.field('registrar', pa.string()),
    pa.field('status', pa.string()),
    
])

table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df, preserve_index=False)
pq.write_table(table, '/tmp/tst2.pa')
df = pd.read_parquet('/tmp/tst2.pa')
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  A few clarifying questions:  
Am I misinterpreting [the .17 changelog](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) (specifically this here: [ARROW-2587](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-2587) where it says this should be possible?  
I have gotten other complex data types (e.g. a list of structs) to work - it seems there's something else going on here.  
Also - what makes me think it's not an issue with these types being unsupported is that it's working _sometimes_ - it just fails for datasets of different sizes.

Comment: Actually I've tested with `0.17.1` and it works for me. Are you sure you have the right version of arrow? run `pa.__version__` to check. As far as why it's working sometimes, if your sample data only contains the null rows, it should work. I suspect that's what is happening.

Comment: I'm 100% positive I'm using `0.17.1`.  To debug machine-specific issues, I ran the code from my original question in Google CoLab and it seems to be working just fine.  So it looks like the issue is something specific to my machine.  I'm going to experiment with different versions of python and compiling arrow from source to see if that fixes it.